# event for continuous change in text of the textbox

Tags: jquery

Hi I need to implement the text change event for a textbox.
I have written below code for the same :

```
$("#peoplepick").on("change paste keyup", function() {
    //some code
});
```

This works but only once, when for the first time text is entered in the textbox. Is there any way that this can be modified to accept the continuous change in the textbox.
like if I type "abcdefgh", event should be raised on every alphabet entered in the textbox.

Comment: `keyup` should be triggered for every character you type.

Comment: Try using 
$( "#target" ).keypress(function() {
console.log( "Handler for .keypress() called." );
}); REFER: http://api.jquery.com/keypress/

Comment: But it's not working this way.

Comment: Make a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: Sorry guy, you all are correct. keyup is working. problem is the inside code that is I am calling a widget inside of it. But does that make any difference? putting a alert pops up every-time. but not the call of the widget. I am not able to understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next code:

```
function handleFunction(){
    //some code
}

$('#peoplepick').bind('keypress', function(){
        setTimeout(handleFunction, 1);
    }
);​
```

Also you can add paste event in addition to keypress if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#peoplepick").on("keyup", function() {
    //some code
});
```

you can try this.

Answer (score -1):

You only need the keyup event.
It is triggered for every key you release, even for the ctrl key if you paste something.

I made a fiddle and it works fine with input and also with textarea as you can see in console log.

```
$("#peoplepick").on("keyup", function() {
    console.log("works");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86G4n/3/)

Maybe you have a typo in your id if it doesnt work.
Post your html maybe.